# Tramp can't connect with ssh: Wrong type argument: "number-or-marker-p undefined"

Tags: tramp, ssh

I'm trying to edit files and execute commands on my virtual GNU/Hurd machine.  However, TRAMP asks for password, connects when correct password given, and finally says:

```
~ $ cd /ssh:akib@192.168.100.230:~
Wrong type argument: "number-or-marker-p undefined"
```

The `ssh` command works without any error or warning, only TRAMP isn't working.

I've tried to change shell prompt according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954479/emacs-tramp-doesnt-work), and even removed non-ASCII characters from `/etc/motd`.  But the problem still persists.

Backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument "number-or-marker-p undefined")
  signal(wrong-type-argument ("number-or-marker-p undefined"))
  tramp-signal-hook-function(wrong-type-argument ("number-or-marker-p undefined"))
  signal(wrong-type-argument ("number-or-marker-p undefined"))
  tramp-maybe-open-connection((tramp-file-name "ssh" "akib" nil "192.168.100.230" nil "~" nil))
  tramp-send-command((tramp-file-name "ssh" "akib" nil "192.168.100.230" nil "~" nil) "cd ~ && pwd")
  tramp-sh-handle-expand-file-name("/ssh:akib@192.168.100.230:~" nil)
  apply(tramp-sh-handle-expand-file-name ("/ssh:akib@192.168.100.230:~" nil))
  tramp-sh-file-name-handler(expand-file-name "/ssh:akib@192.168.100.230:~" nil)
  apply(tramp-sh-file-name-handler expand-file-name ("/ssh:akib@192.168.100.230:~" nil))
  tramp-file-name-handler(expand-file-name "/ssh:akib@192.168.100.230:~" nil)
  expand-file-name("/ssh:akib@192.168.100.230:~")
  cd("/ssh:akib@192.168.100.230:~")
  eshell/cd("/ssh:akib@192.168.100.230:~")
  apply(eshell/cd "/ssh:akib@192.168.100.230:~")
  eshell-exec-lisp(eshell-print eshell-error eshell/cd ("/ssh:akib@192.168.100.230:~") nil)
  eshell-lisp-command(eshell/cd ("/ssh:akib@192.168.100.230:~"))
  eshell-plain-command("cd" ("/ssh:akib@192.168.100.230:~"))
  eshell-named-command("cd" ("/ssh:akib@192.168.100.230:~"))
  (prog1 (eshell-named-command "cd" (list (eshell-extended-glob (eshell-convert (concat "/ssh:akib@192.168.100.230:" "~"))))) (mapc #'funcall eshell-this-command-hook))
  (condition-case err (prog1 (eshell-named-command "cd" (list (eshell-extended-glob (eshell-convert (concat "/ssh:akib@192.168.100.230:" "~"))))) (mapc #'funcall eshell-this-command-hook)) ((debug error) (mapc #'funcall eshell-this-command-hook) (eshell-errorn (error-message-string err)) (eshell-close-handles 1)))
  (condition-case-unless-debug err (prog1 (eshell-named-command "cd" (list (eshell-extended-glob (eshell-convert (concat "/ssh:akib@192.168.100.230:" "~"))))) (mapc #'funcall eshell-this-command-hook)) (error (mapc #'funcall eshell-this-command-hook) (eshell-errorn (error-message-string err)) (eshell-close-handles 1)))
  (eshell-condition-case err (prog1 (eshell-named-command "cd" (list (eshell-extended-glob (eshell-convert (concat "/ssh:akib@192.168.100.230:" "~"))))) (mapc #'funcall eshell-this-command-hook)) (error (mapc #'funcall eshell-this-command-hook) (eshell-errorn (error-message-string err)) (eshell-close-handles 1)))
  (let ((eshell-this-command-hook '(ignore))) (eshell-condition-case err (prog1 (eshell-named-command "cd" (list (eshell-extended-glob (eshell-convert (concat "/ssh:akib@192.168.100.230:" "~"))))) (mapc #'funcall eshell-this-command-hook)) (error (mapc #'funcall eshell-this-command-hook) (eshell-errorn (error-message-string err)) (eshell-close-handles 1))))
  (eshell-trap-errors (eshell-named-command "cd" (list (eshell-extended-glob (eshell-convert (concat "/ssh:akib@192.168.100.230:" "~"))))))
  (progn (eshell-trap-errors (eshell-named-command "cd" (list (eshell-extended-glob (eshell-convert (concat "/ssh:akib@192.168.100.230:" "~")))))))
  (catch 'top-level (progn (eshell-trap-errors (eshell-named-command "cd" (list (eshell-extended-glob (eshell-convert (concat "/ssh:akib@192.168.100.230:" "~"))))))))
  (progn (run-hooks 'eshell-pre-command-hook) (catch 'top-level (progn (eshell-trap-errors (eshell-named-command "cd" (list (eshell-extended-glob (eshell-convert ...))))))) (run-hooks 'eshell-post-command-hook))
  (let ((eshell-current-handles (eshell-create-handles t 'append)) eshell-current-subjob-p) (progn (run-hooks 'eshell-pre-command-hook) (catch 'top-level (progn (eshell-trap-errors (eshell-named-command "cd" (list (eshell-extended-glob ...)))))) (run-hooks 'eshell-post-command-hook)))
  (eshell-commands (progn (run-hooks 'eshell-pre-command-hook) (catch 'top-level (progn (eshell-trap-errors (eshell-named-command "cd" (list (eshell-extended-glob ...)))))) (run-hooks 'eshell-post-command-hook)))
  eval((eshell-commands (progn (run-hooks 'eshell-pre-command-hook) (catch 'top-level (progn (eshell-trap-errors (eshell-named-command "cd" (list ...))))) (run-hooks 'eshell-post-command-hook))))
  eshell-send-input(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eshell-send-input nil)
  call-interactively(eshell-send-input nil nil)
  command-execute(eshell-send-input)
```

I'm using `GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.24, cairo version 1.16.0)` on Guix GNU/Linux.

Comment: Hard to say what's up. I recommend to write a Tramp bug report via `M-x tramp-bug`. Alternatively, you might try the recent Tramp 2.5.1.1 from GNU ELPA.